# Adding/Removing from stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

This removes all of the children on my draggable layer:

```
while(draggableLayer.numChildren){
                draggableLayer.removeChildAt(0);
            }
```

But they just disappear off the stage, how can I add these back on to the stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeChildAt` returns the removed `DisplayObject`. You can store it in an `Array` or another data structure and add it later on if you need it.

```
var removedChildren:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
while(draggableLayer.numChildren)
{
    removedChildren.push(draggableLayer.removeChildAt(0));
}
```